# Force Spring Kafka not to create topics automatically, but to use already created ones

Tags: spring-kafka

There is a quite simple case I would like to implement:
I have a base and DLT topics:

```
MessageBus:
  Topic: my_topic
  DltTopic: my_dlt_topic
  Broker: event-serv:9092
```

So, those topics are already predefined, I don't need to create them automatically.

The only I need to handle broken messages automatically without retries, because they don't make any sense, so I have something like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ["#{config.messageBus.topic}"], groupId = "group_id")
@RetryableTopic(
    dltStrategy = DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR,
    autoCreateTopics = "false",
    attempts = "1"
)
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun consume(rawMessage: String?) {
    ...
}

@DltHandler
fun processMessage(rawMessage: String?) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(config.messageBus.dltTopic, rawMessage)
}
```

That of course doesn't work properly.
I also tried to specify a `kafkaTemplate`

```
@Bean
fun kafkaTemplate(
    config: Config,
    producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, String>
): KafkaTemplate<String, String> {
    val template = KafkaTemplate(producerFactory)
    template.defaultTopic = config.messageBus.dltTopic
    return template
}
```

however, that does not change the situation.

In the end, I believe there is an obvious solution, so I please give me a hint about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documenation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69317126Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69317126Application.class, args);
    }

    @RetryableTopic(attempts = "1", autoCreateTopics = "false", dltStrategy = DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR)
    @KafkaListener(id = "so69317126", topics = "so69317126")
    void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    @DltHandler
    void handler(String in) {
        System.out.println("DLT: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory namer() {
        return new RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory() {

            @Override
            public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(Properties properties) {
                if (properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
                    return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

                        @Override
                        public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                            return "so69317126";
                        }

                    };
                }
                else if(properties.isDltTopic()) {
                    return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProviderFactory.SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

                        @Override
                        public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                            return "so69317126.DLT";
                        }

                    };
                }
                else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Shouldn't get here - attempts is only 1");
                }
            }

        };

    }

}
```

```
so69317126: partitions assigned: [so69317126-0]
so69317126-dlt: partitions assigned: [so69317126.DLT-0]
foo
DLT: foo
```

Comment: That works, thanks. However, there is still a question: In your example `@RetryableTopic(attempts = "1"..)`, and in the JavaDock: "The number of attempts made _before the message is sent to the DLT_." but based on the log there is no more attempts were done. Normally every attempts has a specific log entry. Why is is so?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. 1 attempt means exactly that - no retries, just the initial delivery.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Kafka server configuration so you must set it on the server. The relevant property is:

```
  auto.create.topics.enable (true by default)
```

Comment: Sure, if I set that that property to `false` my application will complain because spring-kafka wants to create its own. @alex is it a solution?